# How to add marks to tests added using metafunc?

Tags: python, pytest

I have some code that generates one test for each .yaml file in a folder.

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "yamlpath" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        files = []
        names = []
        for filename in os.listdir(YAML_FILES_FOLDER):
            if filename.endswith('.yaml') or filename.endswith('.yml'):
                testname = filename.split('.')[0]
                files.append(YAML_FILES_FOLDER / filename)
                names.append(testname)

        metafunc.parametrize("yamlpath", files, ids=names)
```

However, a few of my tests are failing. Therefore, I would like to mark some of them as xfail. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could do it is add one more parameter to your test function that indicates that the test is expected to fail and then you add a

```py
if fails:
    pytest.xfail()
```

branch to the start of the test to [mark the test using code](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/skipping.html#xfail-mark-test-functions-as-expected-to-fail). You then pass the `fails` argument when generating tests.

I made a simpler example with where I just check if a number is even

```py
# conftest.py

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "number" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        names = ["number", "fails"]
        values = []
        for i in range(1, 3):
            values.append([i, not (i % 2 == 0)])
        metafunc.parametrize(names, values)


# test_1.py

import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def number():
    pass

def test_1(number, fails):
    if fails:
        pytest.xfail(reason="Should fail")
    assert number % 2 == 0

def test_2():
    assert True

def test_3():
    assert False
```

This should work for most other marks as well, since most of them seem to have an [equivalent function](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html?highlight=mark).